# TextView text formatting cause last symbol delete on double space

Tags: android, xamarin

I need to format text entered into text view in format "11 11 111111"

I created Custom TextFormatter

```
class DocumentTextWatcher : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    private EditText _et;

    int _state = 0;

    public DocumentTextWatcher(EditText et)
    {
        _et = et;
    }

    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {
        if (_state < 1)
        {
            _state++;

            var text = s.ToString();
            var str = new Java.Lang.String(DocumentFormatter.FormatNumber(text).ToUpperInvariant());

            s.Replace(0, text.Length, str, 0, str.Length());
        }
        else
        {
            _state = 0;
        }
    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }
}
```

i created custom theme for text view

```
<style name="Widget.FinesTheme.Number" parent="Widget.FinesTheme.EditText">    
  <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
  <item name="android:maxLength">12</item>
  <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
  <item name="android:inputType">textCapCharacters|textFilter|textNoSuggestions</item>
  <item name="android:digits">@string/filter_list</item>   
</style>
```

Where filter list is =

```
<'string name="filter_list">0 123456789АВЕКМНОРСТХУABEKMHOPCTXY</string>
```

Almost everything works fine except when i tap space twice it sometimes deletes last symbol. I can not bypass this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue yesterday. There seems to be a bug with Google Keyboard or the EditText implementation. When you double-tap the spacebar, it automatically replaces the two spaces with a period and a space. I think this is where the issue of the last character disappearing comes from.

On to the fix, setting `android:inputType="textPasswordVisible"` seems to resolve the issue.

PS. I see that your digits only include uppercase characters. If you want to capitalize what the user types, you can use `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters"` and add an InputFilter.AllCaps filter to your EditText.